# Calculating the tangent space of an ellipsoid

Tags: manifolds, tangent-spaces

I want to calculate the tangent space of
$$
M^{n - 1}
:= \left\{ x \in \mathbb R^n: \frac{(x^1)^2}{a_1^2}+...+\frac{(x^n)^2}{a_n^2}=1\right\}.
$$
I already proved that this is an $(n-1)$ dimensional manifold.
Now as far as I know, we have
$$
T_xM^{n-1}
=\left\{(x,v)\in T_x\mathbb R^n:\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_iv_i}{a_i^2}=0\right\}.
$$
Is there another way to write this? It just looks not completed yet.